# Open gapps crashing, no GSF id available on LineageOS 15.1

Tags: google-play-services, lineageos, google-apps, 8.1-oreo

I just installed LineageOS 15.1 on my Galaxy Note 4 (SM910F) via TWRP, everything worked out nicely. Now I wanted to add the Gapps to the system in order to use the playstore. I downloaded the zip file from https://opengapps.org/ (ARM/Android 8.1/pico) and installed it with TWRP. After a reboot I keep getting messages that Google Play services repeatedly crashed, about every 10 seconds or so.

After some searching I found out that Google started blocking uncertified devices from using the service, but that there is a way to whitelist your "custom device" by submitting your Google Service Framework ID to Google. To get this GSF ID, I tried the commands given on the page (www.google.com/android/uncertified):

```
$ adb root
$ adb shell 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db "select * from main where name = \"android_id\";"'
```

But this did not work, no ID was found, neither via adb as above, nor in a local root shell directly on the phone. I then tried to read out the ID by using an app called "Device ID" ([as described here](https://saintlad.com/fix-device-not-certified-by-google-error/)), but this app also did not manage to get the GSF ID, the field was blank.

I already wiped the phone and retried the procedure with another gapps package (the "micro" variant), but I ran into the same problem.

Is there something I can do? I would love to use LineageOS, but unfortunately I still do need the Playstore and I really do not want to go back to the stock Android 6.

Comment: According to [LineageOS Wiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/gapps.html), you have to flash gapps before rebooting into LOS for the first time. Have you done that?